# Why did the other Lords accept to be part of the Six Kingdoms so easily?

Tags: game-of-thrones, character-motivation

In the *Game of Thrones* finale, S08E06 *The Iron Throne* we can see Bran the Broken being chosen as King of the 7 Kingdoms, but Sansa claims for the North to be independent hence making the realm of 6 Kingdoms.

We could expect the other Lords to step for their own realms and also asking for independency, especially Asha Greyjoy for the Iron Islands and the Dornish guy. These two Kingdoms have shown history of being reluctant to be part of a whole Westerosi Kingdom.

Comment: Possibly because they were heavily dependent on the central Westroes government for survival.

Comment: Because the episode only had 10 minutes left, so they all knew they had to wrap it up ;)